# How to get access of props in methods in script tag

Tags: vue.js

I have a property passed from it's parent component. The props works perfectly in template (in v-for), but can't access it in methods from script:

My codes from the script :

```
    props: ['singleData'],
    created() {
       console.log(this.singleData)
    },
```

What I am getting in console is :

```
proxy {}
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Object
  [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

From parent component :

```
<UpdateModal v-model="editDialog" :singleData="singleData" />
```

Form script :

```
export default {
    setup() {
        return {
            singleData: ref({}),
        }
    },
    methods: {
       editRow(branch_row) {
          this.editDialog = true
          this.singleData = branch_row  // getting from table row 
          appended in the template
       },
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the data defined and passed in parent component?

Comment: Please check the question again, I have added code from parent at the bottom of my question